# Links and Buttons are Less Responsive on Page with YouTube iframe using iPhone Safari

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe, youtube, mobile-safari

I have a RoR webpage that uses a YouTube iframe which works completely normally with a desktop browser, but for some reason when using Safari on an iPhone, other buttons and links on the page are not very responsive and can take several "clicks" with the thumb to register. The page still works fine for the most part, but I'm hoping to ensure an optimal mobile user experience. Is there something with iframes or YouTube links that mess with how "clickable" other buttons/links are on the same page for iPhones? I won't share the full source code of my page for the sake of brevity, but here's a snippit of the iframe and parent DIV elements.

```
    <div class="m-auto m-width-800">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 workout-video">
        <iframe class="workout-iframe embed-responsive-item" src="https://youtube...blah" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Again, everything still works, I'm just wondering why it can be struggle to click other links and buttons on the page on iPhone safari? The only pages on my entire web application that behave strangely like this on iPhones are the ones with the YouTube iframe elements, so I feel like that has to be the reason...any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this while starting to ask basically the same question. I'll frame my initial answer in that form, since I already wrote it :grin:.

I have a website that has some content, a few links, and then partway down the page has an embedded Google Form in an iframe.

On mobile (I've only tested iPhone), I've found that initially clicking the links requires only a "soft" tap. However, after tapping into the iframe and then scrolling back up to the links, those links require a "harder" tap.

(At first, I thought there must be something wrong with my fingers!)

I was able to fix this issue by adding the following JavaScript to the page:

```
<script>(function(d){
  // fix "hard" link clicks caused by iphone fixation on iframe
  d.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].ontouchstart = function() {
        d.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].focus()
      }
}(document))</script>
```

This returns focus to the `<body>` whenever you touch the `<body`>. This works, but is this a good fix? Is there a better fix?

https://iframe-iphone-focus.glitch.me/ demonstrates the problem and the fix.

Comment: Interesting...I'll have to give this a shot. Seems a little "hacky" but probably better than what I've got now.